# How to specify the scale parameter in robust regression using R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am using the book *"Classical and Modern Regression with Applications"* written by *RAYMOND H.MYERS*, in which the author shows an illustration of robust regression using SAS(page 354, chapter 7.7), while I am a fan of R. Now I want to do the robust regression with the *Huber tuning constant* specified as 1.0 and the initial *scale parameter* specified as 1.5 times the median of the absolute residuals obtained from OLS regression. Have gone through the help file of `rlm()` but have no idea about which parameter meets my requirements(Actually I notice the parameter `scale.est` but it seems to be the method of scale estimation).

Comment: Have you done an R-function search for "Huber" ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I have search for `Huber()` but the return of it is the _MAD scale estimate_, which is not what I am looking for.